# TabItem Header looks different as a Label

Tags: wpf, tabitem

I have a TabItem and was previously setting the Header within the object like so,

```
<TabItem x:Name="Checked_Out_Items" Header="Clients In Use" Height="40" LostFocus="Checked_Out_Items_LostFocus" GotFocus="Checked_Out_Items_GotFocus" BorderThickness="0" >
```

However, I've run into the problem where there is not a Click event for this Tab. I found a solution where we can insert a label as the header specified here, 
[how to handle TabItem single click event in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727323/how-to-handle-tabitem-single-click-event-in-wpf)

But, the Label looks nothing like what I need. Here is the Tab Header defined inside the object. [image]

Here's what it looks like with the label

```
        <TabItem x:Name="Checked_Out_Items" Height="40" LostFocus="Checked_Out_Items_LostFocus" GotFocus="Checked_Out_Items_GotFocus" BorderThickness="0" >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Label Content="Clients In Use" Height="40" MouseLeftButtonDown="Checked_Out_Items_Clicked" Width="171" />
            </TabItem.Header>
```

[image]

Comment: How does a label look for you when you place it somewhere else in the application? Maybe its just a default style defined somewhere in the app resources.

Comment: @grek40 They look the same, so it must be a default style.

Comment: Another side note to the clicking topic: Just listen to `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` on the `TabItem`, because unlike the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event it will actually be fired ;)

Comment: Use `ContentControl` instead of label, or set the `Label`'s style to an empty style without a `BasedOn` attribute.

Comment: @TalenKylon sorry, had a little misconception there. The Text without `Label` is styled specially and that style is not transferred to the label.

Comment: @grek40 The PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown fires on the click of the Tab, as well as any clicks of the objects inside of that tab. It will not work for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets separate the concerns a bit.

In order to handle a mouse click event, a control needs to be prepared for receiving this event, it needs to implement a handler and the handler must actually receive the event. In case of `TabItem` the mouse click event is consumed by the control, without releasing the event to user defined listeners.

On the level of `TabItem`, the best option would be to handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event, but this is not an option if event handling shouldn't occur when child controls have their own handling functionality.

So the other option is to handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event before it reaches the `TabItem`, which means to handle it in a child control of the tab item.

As said, in order to receive the event, the control needs to be ready to receive the event. This means, it needs a `Background` not `null` (can be `Transparent`) and `IsHitTestEnabled="True"` (which is default in most cases) and it must actually handle the event.

For the showcase, I use a `Red` instead of `Transparent` background color. The red area is the place where mouse clicks are captured and handled.

```
<TabItem Padding="0">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <Border Height="30" Width="50"
                Background="Red" MouseLeftButtonDown="Item_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <ContentPresenter
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Content="T2"/>
        </Border>
    </TabItem.Header>
    Test Content 2
</TabItem>
```

Or, in order to have a better separation between header content and click handling, a `HeaderTemplate` can be used:

```
<TabItem Header="T3" Padding="0">
    <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border MinHeight="30" MinWidth="50"
                    Background="Red" MouseLeftButtonDown="Item_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <ContentPresenter
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
    Test Content 3
</TabItem>
```

The issue with any approach that relies on child controls is, that there is still a border of the `TabItem` and if the user clicks that border, the click will be outside of the child control and the tab will be selected without executing the click handler.

So a different way to handle tab changes (not clicks!) would be to handle the `TabControl.SelectionChanged` event and filter for events that actually originate from the `TabControl` and not from some inner content elements.

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source == sender)
    {
        // this selection change is actually issued because of a tab change
    }
}
```

Another thing I just realized: The same condition could be used in `TabItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` in order to filter clicks to the tabitem header vs click events originating from the content area.

Edit:

The reason why `Label` is looking different is, that a font style is active for `TabItem` and `Label` is using some of its internal styles, ignoring the `TabItem` style.